# ¿Cómo hacer que se muevan las palas?

Tags: javascript

No entiendo muy bien como va el funcionamiento de los FPS ni ese tipo de cosas, especulo que en algún lado posiblemente deba usar set interval (o puede que haya muchas más formas de hacerlo), sin embargo no se me ocurre como mover los palos, y allá donde busco no me entero. Mi objetivo es crear el clásico juego de las palas con la bola que rebota, sé usar el canvas pero hasta ahí llego... No logro que se mueva nada de su sitio y me resulta frustrante. Les dejo aquí el código, muchas gracias.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Juego de palas</title>


    <style>

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="lienzo" width="1000" height="640" style="border: 3px solid black"></canvas><br>
        <script>
            //Declaración de variables
            var c = document.getElementById("lienzo");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var x1 = 40;//x jugador 1
            var y1 = 280;//y jugador 1
            var x2 = 940;//x jugador 2
            var y2 = 280;//y jugador 2
            var x3 = 500;//x pelota
            var y3 = 320;//y pelota
            function juego() {
            //Palo izquierdo (Jugador 1)
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
            ctx.lineTo(40, 330);
            ctx.stroke();

            //Palo derecho (Jugador 2)
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
            ctx.lineTo(940, 330);
            ctx.stroke();

            //Bola
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x3, y3, 7, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            }
            //Mover palo izquierdo
            c.addEventListener("keydown", pulsarTecla, false);

            function pulsarTecla(e){
                var tecla = e.keyCode

                if (tecla == 81) {
                    y1 += 5;
                }

                if (tecla == 65) {
                    y1 -= 5;
                }
        }
        </script>
        <button onclick="juego()">Comenzar juego</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El **canvas** es un **lienzo**, un papel en blanco en el cual puedes pintar un "único" dibujo, para crear una animación deberías poder **pintar** y **borrar** por completo este **lienzo** tantas veces como sea posible, para de esta forma crear el efecto de **animación entre dibujos**.

Para realizar una animación lo primero que necesitarías es una función que sea capas de ejecutarse en lo posible **60 veces por segundo**, para ellos los navegadores disponen de un método llamado [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame).

Algo así:

```
function repintar() {
  borrarCanvas();
  pintarCanvas();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(repintar);
}
```

Este código lo que hace es ejecutarse en lo posible a **60FPS** y entre cada interacción va a llamar a estas dos funciones:

- **borrarCanvas**: La cual se encargara de **borrar** el canvas por completo.
- **pintarCanvas**: La cual se encargara de **pintar** el nuevo dibujo.

Este seria el código que habías compartido pero agregándole estas pequeñas modificaciones.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Juego de palas</title>

    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas
      id="lienzo"
      width="1000"
      height="640"
      style="border: 3px solid black"
    ></canvas
    ><br />
    <script>
      //Declaración de variables
      var c = document.getElementById("lienzo");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var x1 = 40; //x jugador 1
      var y1 = 280; //y jugador 1
      var x2 = 940; //x jugador 2
      var y2 = 280; //y jugador 2
      var x3 = 500; //x pelota
      var y3 = 320; //y pelota
      var hPlayer = 50; // Alto de cada jugador
      var play = false; // Empezar a jugar

      function pintarCanvas() {
        //Palo izquierdo (Jugador 1)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x1, y1 + hPlayer);
        ctx.stroke();

        //Palo derecho (Jugador 2)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
        ctx.lineTo(x2, y2 + hPlayer);
        ctx.stroke();

        //Bola
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x3, y3, 7, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
      }

      function pulsarTecla(e) {
        var tecla = e.keyCode;

        // Tecla Q
        if (tecla == 81) {
          y1 -= 5;
        }

        // Tecla A
        if (tecla == 65) {
          y1 += 5;
        }

        // Tecla ↑
        if (tecla == 38) {
          y2 -= 5;
        }

        // Tecla ↓
        if (tecla == 40) {
          y2 += 5;
        }
      }

      function borrarCanvas() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
      }

      function repintar() {
        borrarCanvas();
        pintarCanvas();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(repintar);
      }

      function empezar() {
        if (!play) {
          play = true;
          //Mover palo izquierdo
          document.addEventListener("keydown", pulsarTecla, false);
          //Iniciar el repintado en lo posible a 60FPS
          repintar();
        }
      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="empezar()">Comenzar juego</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenes que usar setInterval para redibujar el canvas en una cantidad de ciclos cortos que hace parecer la "ilusion" de movimiento, hace un rato me hice el mismo ejercicio por diversion aquí puedes revisar su aplicación
https://github.com/aumartinez/js-pong-game/blob/master/js/main.js

```
//JS Script

window.addEventListener("load", run, false);

function run() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //Ball Start position  
  let initX = canvas.width / 2;
  let initY = canvas.height / 2;

  let x = initX;
  let y = initY;

  //Ball Displacement  
  let dx = 3;
  let dy = dx;

  //Ball
  let ballRad = 8;
  let ballHit = false;

  //User paddle  
  let paddW = 10;
  let paddH = 50;

  let paddHit = false;

  let movY = 5;

  let userX = 0;
  let userY = (canvas.height / 2) - (paddH / 2);

  //PC paddle  
  let pcX = canvas.width - paddW;
  let pcY = userY;

  let pcSpeed = 2;

  //Scores
  let userScore = 0;
  let pcScore = 0;

  //Paddle movement controls init
  let upKey = false;
  let downKey = false;

  //Listeners
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownFn, false);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpFn, false);

  //Canvas redraw
  let time = 10;
  let canvasDraw = setInterval(draw, time);

  function draw() {    
    //Clear Canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //Move ball - ball limits    
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    if (x > canvas.width) {
      x = 0 + 15;
      y = initY;
      userScore++;
      if(userScore == 10) {        
        clearInterval(canvasDraw);
        alert("You Won");
        document.location.reload();
      }
    }    
    if (x < 0) {
      x = canvas.width - 15;
      y = initY;
      pcScore++;
      if(pcScore == 10) {        
        clearInterval(canvasDraw);
        alert("You Lost");
        document.location.reload();
      }
    }

    //Top and bottom bounces
    if (y + dy < ballRad) {
      dy = -dy;
    }
    else if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRad) {
      dy = -dy;
    }

    //User Paddle movement
    if (upKey && (userY) > 0) {
      userY -= movY;
    }
    else if (downKey && userY < (canvas.height - paddH)) {
      userY += movY;
    }

    //PC paddle movement
    if (dy < 0 && pcY > 0) {
      pcY -= pcSpeed;
    }
    else if (dy > 0 && pcY < (canvas.height - paddH)) {
      pcY += pcSpeed;
    }

    //Draw objects
    drawBall(ballHit);
    drawPadd(userX, userY, paddW, paddH, paddHit);
    drawPadd(pcX, pcY, paddW, paddH, paddHit);
    drawUserScore();
    drawPcScore();
    drawLabel();
    collDetection(x, y, userX, userY);
    collDetection(x, y, pcX, pcY);    

  }//End draw

  function drawBall(ballHit) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRad, 0 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI);
    let ballColor = (ballHit)? "red" : "#000";    
    ctx.fillStyle = ballColor;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawPadd(paddX, paddY, paddW, paddH, paddHit) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(paddX, paddY, paddW, paddH);
    let paddColor = (paddHit)? "#555" : "#000";
    ctx.fillStyle = paddColor;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawUserScore(){
    ctx.font = "40px Quantico";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#555";
    ctx.fillText(userScore, 45, 45);
  }

  function drawPcScore() {
    ctx.font = "40px Quantico";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#555";    
    ctx.fillText(pcScore, canvas.width - 45, 45);
  }

  function drawLabel() {
    ctx.font = "40px Quantico";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText("Best of 10", canvas.width/2, 45);
  }

  function keyDownFn(evt) {
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
      case 38: //up arrow
      upKey = true;
      break;

      case 40: //down arrow
      downKey = true;
      break;

      default:
      return false;
    }
  }

  function keyUpFn(evt) {
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
      case 38: //up arrow
      upKey = false;
      break;

      case 40: //down arrow
      downKey = false;
      break;

      default:
      return false;
    }
  }

  function collDetection(ballX, ballY, paddX, paddY) {
    let limitTop = paddY;
    let limitBott = paddY + paddH;
    let limitRight = paddX;
    let limitLeft = paddX + paddW;

    if(ballX < limitLeft && ballX > limitRight) {
      if(ballY < limitBott && ballY > limitTop) {
        dx = -dx;
        ballHit = true;
        paddHit = true;
      }  
    }
    else {
      ballHit = false;
      paddHit = false;
    }

    return;
  }

} //End run
```

Comment: Me la puede soplar tu downvote